# How to log out using rest framework jwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

How to log out using rest framework jwt.

How can I close the existing token for the logged-in user?

Just as there is a `get_jwt_token` function, is there a function to break or close?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a django JWT token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40604877/how-to-delete-a-django-jwt-token)

Answer (score 3):

The best way I found to do this was create a `jwt_secret` field in the User model, along with a property to get it, and use `uuid` to set the value. Then set the `JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY` in `settings.py` to that property. When you want to logout, you reset that `jwt_secret` which in turn makes all tokens generated with the old `jwt_secret` invalid. I read about it and got started with it from this blog post https://tag1consulting.com/blog/building-api-django-20-part-i