# How to logout and destory token in PyJWT Django?

Tags: django, jwt, token, logout, pyjwt

I have make a token in **PyJWT** like this:

```
import jwt
import datetime

payload = {
    "id": 1,
    "exp": datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1000),
    "iat": datetime.datetime.utcnow()
}
token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
```

And sent to front and also retrive my payload like this:

```
payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
```

And now i want to destroy token in server and logout.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution. ***JWT tokens** are not destroyable*. And best way for us to do is make a table in our database like blacklist and add dead tokens ito it when call **logout** method.
And then when try to check user token validation just check that table and if the token exist, you should not accept user and `return User Not Authenticated`.

**Be successful**

Comment: One of main advantages of JWT is that you've able to authenticate user without accessing Database. You just need to check if signing is correct. But checking for dead tokens in DB eliminates this feature. Because of it lifetime ot token should be extremely short (about few minutes). And it should be reissued any time using `refresh token`. However I understand that you have to change whole auth architecure to add refresh tokens and that may be impossible in your case

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726066/jwt-refresh-token-flow) is a good question about JWT

Answer (score 0):

Change secret key from settings.

Note that this will effectively log out ALL your users. No JWTs issued with the old key will be valid.